# console cannot log state

Tags: javascript, console.log, react-state-management

Trying to log information from state to console returns the error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.userName')'

I am very new to JS and so I really dont know how this works or how it's supposed to work

I tried replacing 'this.state.userName' with

```
 - (userName) => this.getState(userName)
 - this.state[userName]
 - 'this.state[1]
```

None of these had the desired effect

Here is my code:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName:'User Name',
      userEmail:'',
      loggedIn: false,
    };
  }

  login() {
    console.log(this.state.userName);
  };
```

I simply want the console to log whatever is assigned to userName, namely 'User Name'

login is called through:
`onPress={this.login}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined is not an object evaluating this.state.\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445631/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-state)

Comment: You need to bind `login` with `this` in the constructor: `this.login = this.login.bind(this)`

Comment: How is `login` being called? I agree with [adiga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660019/console-cannot-log-state#comment99889344_56660019) that this looks like a scope issue. In other words, `this` is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: `onPress={this.login.bind(this)}` or `onPress={() => this.login()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found (26/06/19):

```
onPress={this.login.bind(this)} or onPress={() => this.login()}
```

Found by: [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick way to explore an object and you'll likely see what's causing the problem:

```js
console.dir( this.state );
```

It will dump an expandable view of the object to the console, so you can see what's in it and what it's properties are.